# White space after running flutter build apk --release

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a simple flutter application. the debug version works very ok but the release version shows white space when I tried to navigate to a screen from dashboard. I don't know what's causing this. I tried to run. I have tried to run the shared_preference without the version number it didn't work. Here's the error message below:

```
flutter build apk --release --verbose
```

And I got this:

```
[ +205 ms] > Task :shared_preferences:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
[   +2 ms]
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:9: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask in android.os has been deprecated
[   +2 ms] import android.os.AsyncTask;
[        ]                  ^
[   +1 ms]
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask in android.os has been deprecated
[   +1 ms]     new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
[   +1 ms]         ^
[        ]
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask() in AsyncTask has been deprecated
[   +2 ms]     new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
[   +1 ms]     ^
[   +1 ms]
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:123: warning: [deprecation] doInBackground(Params...) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
[   +2 ms]       protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
[   +1 ms]                         ^
[        ]   where Params,Result are type-variables:
[   +1 ms]     Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
[        ]     Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
[   +1 ms] > Task :sqflite:javaPreCompileRelease
[        ] > Task :shared_preferences:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
[        ]
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask() in AsyncTask has been deprecated
[   +1 ms]     new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
[        ]                                          ^
[        ]
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:128: warning: [deprecation] onPostExecute(Result) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
[   +1 ms]       protected void onPostExecute(Boolean value) {
[   +2 ms]                      ^
[   +1 ms]   where Result is a type-variable:
[   +1 ms]     Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
[   +1 ms]
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:131: warning: [deprecation] execute(Params...) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
[   +1 ms]     }.execute();
[        ]      ^
[        ]   where Params,Progress,Result are type-variables:
[        ]     Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
[        ]     Progress extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
[        ]     Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
[        ] 7 warnings
[+1155 ms] > Task :barcode_scan:compileReleaseKotlin
```

Here's my pubspec.yaml file below:

```
name: egtai
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0" 
  # 
  # >=2.12.0 <3.0.0

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  barcode_scan: ^1.0.0
  google_fonts: ^0.3.5
  date_time_picker: ^2.0.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
  page_transition: ^2.0.2
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+3
  get: ^4.1.4
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.1
  pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/notification.png
    - assets/images/calendar.png
    - assets/images/festival.png
    - assets/images/food.png
    - assets/images/map.png
    - assets/images/setting.png
    - assets/images/todo.png
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: PoppinsBlack
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-Black.ttf
    - family: PoppinsBlackItalic
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-BlackItalic.ttf

    - family: PoppinsBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-Bold.ttf
    - family: PoppinsBoldItalic
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-BoldItalic.ttf

    - family: PoppinsExtraBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-ExtraBold.ttf
    - family: PoppinsExtraBoldItalic
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf

    - family: PoppinsExtraLight
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-ExtraLight.ttf
    - family: PoppinsExtraLightItalic
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-ExtraLightItalic.ttf
    - family: PoppinsItalic
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-Italic.ttf
    - family: PoppinsLight
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-Light.ttf

    - family: PoppinsLightItalic
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-LightItalic.ttf
    - family: PoppinsMedium
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf
    - family: PoppinsMediumItalic
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-MediumItalic.ttf
    - family: PoppinsRegular
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf

    - family: PoppinsSemiBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
    - family: PoppinsSemiBoldItalic
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
    - family: PoppinsThin
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-Thin.ttf
    - family: PoppinsThinItalic
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/Poppins/Poppins-ThinItalic.ttf

  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Please what can I do to resolve this. I have tried adding this in the bundle.gradle:

```
    release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
        }
```

Still it didn't work. Any suggestion I will gladly appreciate.

Comment: this may happen because of some exceptions like null values or overflow. are you sure your app doesn't have any exceptions or possible null values?

Comment: I got an exception that said improper use of parent widget. after I resolved it, everything worked fine. Thanks very much @AbdelrahmanM.Elmarakby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I go an exception that said improper use of parent widget. after I resolved it, everything worked fine. Thanks very much @AbdelrahmanM.Elmarakby